# is there a way to update a div with new content only using ajax

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

This is the div that i am updating

but i want to add a active class to the (li) item 
every time the div refreshes the active class goes away
so i don`t want to refresh all the data in the (ul) but 
only add (li) if there is a new data in the database,
with out refreshing the previous (li) items

```
<div id="contacts">
    <ul id="rooms" class="rooms">
        <!-- This is where the data get inserted -->

        <!-- the ajax call and this  -->

        <li class='contact' data-val='<?php echo $room['id']; ?>'>
            <div class='wrap'>
                <div class='meta'>  
                    <p class='name'><?php echo $room['sender']; ?></p>
                    <p class='preview'><?php echo $room['senderemail']; ?></p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </li>


    </ul>
</div>
```

this is my ajax call

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var interval = setInterval(function(){
        $.ajax({
            url: 'rooms.php',
            success: function(data){
                $('#rooms').html(data);
            }
        });
    }, 1000);
});
```

in the room php

```
    $rooms = get_rooms();
    foreach($rooms as $room){
        ?>
        <li class='contact' data-val='<?php echo $room['id']; ?>'>
            <div class='wrap'>
                <div class='meta'>  
                    <p class='name'><?php echo $room['sender']; ?></p>
                    <p class='preview'><?php echo $room['senderemail']; ?></p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </li>
        <?php
    }
```

the get_rooms() function

```
function get_rooms() {
        $sql = "SELECT id, sender, senderemail FROM chatroom ";
        $result = mysqli_query($GLOBALS['dbh'], $sql);
        $rooms = array();   
        while($room = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
            $rooms[] = array('id'=>$room['id'], 'sender'=>$room['sender'], 
                              'senderemail'=>$room['senderemail']);
        }
        return $rooms;
}
```

Comment: You can look at the jquery append method? https://api.jquery.com/append/
I would strongly encourage having a unique ID for these elements so you can check via ID whether its already present on the page

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You Just need to push new data to the div as below just replace your line with:

```
$('#rooms').append(data);
```

> this will add new `<li>` in your existing `<div>` after the last `<li>`

[jquery append()](https://api.jquery.com/append/)

To get the id of the last `<li>`

```
var lastId = $( "#rooms li" ).last().attr('id');
```

Once you get the last id then pass it in your ajax call.

Comment: The rooms.php send all the contacts, so also existing contacts will be added at the end...

Comment: Ok..so in that case $('#rooms').html(data); this is fine...so what do you want to do after replacing html?

Comment: need to check for the id of the last `<li>` that got added so i only append new data not all the data

Comment: @DewaldLouw i have updated my code to get the last li id. pls. have a look.

Comment: thanks for the help.  I have passed lastId   but cant use it in `sql = "SELECT id, sender, senderemail FROM chatroom WHERE id >".$lastId."";` I get a warning: mysqli_fetch_assoc() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, bool given in

Comment: You need to access it via $_post['lastid'] then you can pass it to select query.

Answer (score 0):

You need to simply update your JS code like:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
var active_list = '';
var interval = setInterval(function(){
    $.ajax({
        url: 'rooms.php',
        beforeSend: function(){
            active_list = $('#rooms').find('li.contact.active').attr('data-val');
        }
        success: function(data){
            $('#rooms').html(data);
            $(data).find('li[data-val="' + active_list +'"]').addClass('active');
        }
    });
}, 1000);
```

});

This should solve your problem and Let me know if you still face any issue.

Comment: the active class gets added when i click on the li item.  the problem is the ul gets refreshed every second so i loose the active class. there is only li that is active at a time

Comment: Please confirm and clear me, if you want to add an active class on click? OR it is already adding an active class on click?

Comment: Also confirm, If you want to add active class to all the `li` items in `ul`? OR just want keep the latest `li` as active?

Comment: i want to add the active class only on 'li that has been clicked  so if i click on the second `li` then only the second `li` needs to be active but when the ajax get called all the `li` gets refreshed so i lose the active class on the second `li`

Comment: Updated my answer, now it will work for your requirment

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, your problem is that you lose the active class (which you clicked on the li container) when there is new data.

This has to do with the fact that you exchange all of the content.

There are now three options. Either

1. You give the rooms.php the id of the currently active li-container
   and this script sets the active class for the affected container.
2. You transfer all the chatrooms (ids) already shown to rooms.php and only
   load the new ones (this means effort later with sorting).
3. You save the active li class and re set it after content changed (this is the fastest)

f.e: in your Ajax succes functions:

```
let id=0;
let active_li = $('li.active');
if (active_li.length>0) id=active_li.data('val');
$('#rooms').html(data);
if (id!=0) $('li[data-val="'+id+'"]').addClass ('active');
```

A few other thoughts:

Note the interval of 1000ms. Possible it makes Problems if the request lasts longer than 1000ms. This may still work well in your tests, but maybe not anymore if there are a hundred or 1000 users in your application.

Doesn't it make sense to tell the server when you click the active room and save it in a session so that the server knows which room is active in the client?